# How can edges be selected using arbor js?

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization, arbor.js

Do arbor js have such API to select edges? 
As far as I know, the nearest(screenPoint) only returns the point, node, and distance. Are there any method to determine which edge is selected?

Comment: What do you mean with "be selected"? When clicked? Sorry but I'm not getting what you want... please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: yep, when clicked. More specifically:clicked and return the edge id or object or anything that can access the edge